# Compare the date from a API key value in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I have a scenerio where I need to compare a date from an API response with today's date and check whether it is less than or equal.

The API response will give me a JSON object and in that JSON the key " License" will contain a date in the format "13-Aug-2019",I need to compare this date with today's date and if today's date is greater than "13-Aug-2019" gives a fail in the test results .

Below is the code I wrote to get the date in the license string and today's date,

```
Var body = JSON.parse(response Body);
Var body date=body["license"]
//Sample license value is " license cs code1 version 13-aug- 
2018 cnts ......"
var words = bodydate.split(' ');
license_valid_till=words[4]; // This will get the string 13-aug- 
2019
 console.log(license_valid_till)

 Var ts = new Date();
 var part=ts.toDateString();
 var dpart = part.split(' ');
 today_date=dpart[2] + "-" +dpart[1] +"-"+ dpart[3];
 //This will get the string 12-aug-2019
 console.log(today_date)
```

Now my question is how can I compare this two values,any suggestions will be of great help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pm.test("Check birthday greater than 1988-18-01", () => {
    let date,
        isoFormatDate,
        a = new Date('1988-01-18').getTime();

    for (i = 0; i < jsonData.content.length; i++) {

        date = jsonData.content[i].birthday;

        isoFormatDate = new Date(Date.parse(date)).getTime(); // Converting to integer from date format

        pm.expect(isoFormatDate).to.be.above(a);
    }
});
```

Please use the above code snippet as a reference.